# Videos are "choppy"/"laggy" - Just aren't smooth on web server

Tags: html5, video, video-hosting

I have a video (background) for my website and (I'm sure there's a much more technical word for this) it's choppy, to say the least. I'm wondering if a) I can render it into a better format (file details below) for playback, or b) if it's just my server (details below):

```
Video file:
[Video][1]
Size: 52.0MB
resolution: 1920x1080
Data Rate: 15,962kbps
Toal Bitrate: 16,156kbps
Frame Rate: 14 frames/second (lowered from 30 in attempt to resolve issue)
```

Server Specs (not great, but on a low budget):

```
Dell Precision 490
Intel Xeon 5150 @ 2.66 GHz x 2
4GB RAM DDR2 FB-DIMM @ 533 MHz
Debian 8.4.0
Connection: Shaw Business, 60MB/s-D 5MB/s-U
```

I know this may be more information than needed... But better too much than too little right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think your webserver has much to do with it. I'm guessing it's the bandwith at the users end. It plays at 16,962kbps, which stand for 16,962kb/sec, which is roughly about 16mb per sec.
Your actual video is compressed, it gets decompressed when playing, (That's why the file is smaller), but even the compressed stream has to go quite fast. Most connections don't go that fast, so it gets laggy.

What you want is to lower the bandwith. This can be done by lowering the quality to 90%. If it's just a background, 80% might not be a problem either. Alternatively, you could lower the resolution. Both solution will lower the quality, but will result in lower bandwidths.

---

If you can, just upload it to Youtube, and use their HTML5 embed API to play it in the background. Better browser support, responsive bitrates, fast playback, not your bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks, Man! I lowered the quality to get it to about 5MB using HandBrake. works perfectly now. I will probably raise the quality a bit but at least now I have narrowed it down to what it is I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

52MB is pretty big size for a website video background and your data rate is around 15 Mbps which is very high. A typical video background should be around 4-8MB with datarate of around 3-4Mbps.

Comment: Didn't saw martijn answer while posting. Ignore it.

Comment: You can just delete an answer if you don't think it will be helpful (which is recommended).